# how to specify conditional expression under parameters seciton - Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to have if condition under `parameters` in Azure pipeline yml file. Please find my code below:

I want to show `iPhone 13, iPhone 13 Pro, iPhone SE` if `product` is selected as `phone`. And show `Macbook Pro, Macbook Air` if `product` is selected as `computer` and so on. But I'm getting an below error if I try to add the conditional statement inside `parameters`

**Pipeline Error:**

```
Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/azure-pipeline.yml (Line: 17, Col: 5): A template expression is not allowed in this context
/azure-pipeline.yml (Line: 21, Col: 5): A template expression is not allowed in this context
```

**Pipeline code:**

```
trigger:
  - none

parameters:
  - name: product
    displayName: Select Product
    type: string
    default: phone
    values:
      - phone
      - computer
      - watch

  - name: selectProduct
    displayName: Select Product
    type: string
    ${{ if eq(parameters.product, 'phone') }}:
      values:
        - iPhone 13
        - iPhone 13 Pro
        - iPhone SE
    ${{ if eq(parameters.product, 'computer') }}:
      values:
        - Macbook Pro
        - Macbook Air
    ${{ if eq(parameters.product, 'watch') }}:
      values:
        - Apple Watch Series 7
        - Apple Watch SE
```

Can someone please suggest how can I handle this in azure pipeline, incase if condition is not supported under `parameters` section - what's the alternative approach.

Any help would he much appreciated. Thanks!

**Note:** I want to show this option before pipeline job trigger/submit. This options should pop up when I click `Run Pipeline` button.

Comment: Same question! I would like to render new fields based on user inputs from parameters

Answer (score 2):

> how to specify conditional expression under parameters seciton - Azure DevOps Pipeline

I am afraid it it impossible to runtime parameters conditionally define values based on another parameter value.

You could check the document [Template expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#template-expressions):

> Template expressions can expand template parameters, and also
> variables. You can use parameters to influence how a template is
> expanded. The parameters object works like the variables object in an
> expression. Only predefined variables can be used in template
> expressions.
>
> **Expressions are only expanded for stages, jobs, steps, and containers (inside resources).** You cannot, for example, use an
> expression inside trigger or a resource like repositories.
> Additionally, on Azure DevOps 2020 RTW, you can't use template
> expressions inside containers.

As workaround, we could try to use condition in the stages, jobs, steps with template, like:

```
parameters:
  - name: product
    displayName: Select Product
    type: string
    default: phone
    values:
      - phone
      - computer
      - watch

stages:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.product, 'phone') }}:
    - template: template.yml
      parameters:
        selectProduct:
        - iPhone 13
        - iPhone 13 Pro
        - iPhone SE
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.product, 'computer') }}:
    - template: template.yml 
      parameters:
        selectProduct:
        - Macbook Pro
        - Macbook Air
```

Comment: In your example Leo, what is referring to "template.yml" ?